# Tomcat - launch exe from web application

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I'm using Windows OS. I have written a web application tha launch an external EXE.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Programmi\\A\\a.exe");
p.waitFor();
```

The problem is that when i launch tomcat via startup.bat it function. If I install the Tomcat as service the exe is not launched.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try with the real path `C:\Program Files\A\a.exe`? `C:\Programmi` is a virtual path that depends on the user's locale (Tomcat as a service is run as the `SYSTEM` user by default).

Comment: I change in "C:\\Program Files\\A\A.exe" but the command is not launched and the exit code is 0

Comment: How do you tell whether the command was executed or not?

Comment: I launch a external printer command but is not executed. If I start tomcat with startup.bat is ok

Comment: It is probably a question of network credentials (yours vs `SYSTEM` user). Did you try configuring the Tomcat service to run as your user?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Run **Procrun Monitor Application** (`bin/tomcat*w.exe` of your Tomcat installation) and change the configuration in the _"Log On"_ tab.

Comment: I change to Local system account ad This account to administrator but the result is the same